# RelayCommand for handling changes in TextBox

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light

I am new to MVVM and MVVM-light.
I always see RelayCommand being used to handle Button's Command action. So it will invoke a service operation aysnc. 
My question is how can I use it to handle TextBox changes in the text it is holding? How can I relay that change to the Server side using service? Should I use RelayCommand too?

Answer (score 0):

Typically it's not needed. If you bind the TextBox Text property to a member of your viewmodel and set its UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged then your bound member will get called as soon as the value of the textbox changes i.e. whenever the user presses a key:

```
private string _myString;
public string MyString
{
    get { return this._myString; }
    set { this._myString = value; /**** user pressed a key, respond to it here *****/}
}
```

It's also possible to set up an Event Trigger and intercept the windows messages directly, but I suspect that's not really what you need here.